# Работа с библиотекой okhttp3

Tags: php, java, android, okhttp

Всем привет, у меня небольшой вопрос.
Я пишу приложение **Используя язык программирования Java** и мне нужно реализовать подключение между php сервером и моим приложением используя okhttp3. Я хочу, чтобы моё приложение подключилось к серверу и ждало его указаний не отключаясь от сервера вообще (Не считая сбоев с сетью и других лагов).
Такое возможно? Если да - **как?**
Я не очень силён в работе с сетью (Совсем не силён).

Comment: Для постоянного соединения вам лучше посмотреть в сторону сокет-соединений. HTTP - это всё-таки запрос-ответ

Comment: Но работа то идёт с php сервером

Comment: на php можно и сокеты слушать

Comment: [вот](https://habr.com/ru/post/209864/) [цикл](http://habrahabr.ru/company/ifree/blog/210228/) [статей](https://habr.com/ru/company/ifree/blog/211504/) на эту тему

Comment: А с java использовать подключение простых сокетов? ну т.е. вместо okhttp3 испoльзовать ClientSocket?

Comment: по java не могу сказать достоверно, но похоже на правду